# I was born 20 years ago, but my brothers are born every year

Tags: riddle

> I was born 20 years ago, but my brothers are born every year

Who Am I ?

Hint 1 :

> Chase

Hint 2 :

> I have my own needs.

Source: see [here](https://able2know.org/topic/235273-1)

Comment: logical-deduction are you sure?

Comment: Not sure.. So edited

Comment: If you took this puzzle from the cited link, which does not contain an answer, does the OP actually know the answer? On what basis will the correct answer be chosen?

Comment: The linked forum thread is from 2014.  So, "20 years ago" means 1994?

Comment: Maybe a coincidence, but rot13(gurer vf n 1994 svyz pnyyrq Gur Punfr).

Comment: @Astralbee I know the answer and I can choose which one is correct. I will wait sometime if I haven’t seen right then will post my answer

Answer (score 1):

> Palau?  The country that got its independence in 1994, 20 years before the original question. May be it's citizens are "brothers"? Not sure about how the hints match though.

Answer (score 0):

You could be:

> The Diamondbacks, the Arizona major league baseball team. First formed [20 years ago](https://www.mlb.com/dbacks/fans/20th-anniversary), the "brothers" the riddle is referring to could be the team each year, which changes.

Hint 1:

> [Chase... Field](https://www.mlb.com/dbacks/ballpark)

Hint 2:

> Everyone on the team has different needs. The team itself has needs, namely to win and make money.

Comment: I don't think that is the answer since the link to the original riddle is from 2014

Comment: Thanks for your research. it’s not the answer I’m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This fits the question as asked, although not the hints...

> The first euro coin was minted [20 years ago](http://edition.cnn.com/WORLD/europe/9805/11/euro.money/) in 1998. New coins are made every year.

Comment: Good try, nope wrong answer. I thought euro came to use in 2002